# Can you import exe4j script/project into install4j?

Tags: install4j, exe4j

Is it possible to import exe4j project into install4j? I have some legacy exe4j projects which I would like to import into install4j project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, but you can do the following:

In your install4j project add a launcher (with arbitrary configuration) and open the project file in a text editor. Locate the launcher element and swap it out with the contents of your exe4j file.